# Will there be security updates for 3.1 once 3.2 is released?

Tags: security

I am currently running WordPress 3.1.2 on PHP 5.1.6. The minimum requirement for WordPress 3.2 is going to be PHP 5.2.4 or greater. If I keep running WordPress 3.1.2 and there is a security issue will they provide security updates for 3.1 or will I be forced to upgrade my version of PHP so that I can upgrade to WordPress 3.2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WordPress backports security updates usually 1-3 versions back but they don't promise anything.

The WordPress [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) philosophy is that LTS = "[Long Term Suckage](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-June/032483.html)"

The Long Term Suckage theory is:

> While I like the theory of LTS, what
> happens in practice is it covers up
> the incompetence of IT or developers
> because they put off small slightly
> painful upgrades until they get so out
> of date of trunk (3 years? 5  years?)
> and you have to go through a giant,
> painful, screws everybody  over
> upgrade. --[Matt Mullenweg](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-June/032483.html)

Like how your sysadmin doesn't want to update PHP now that it's 6 years old and 2 major branches behind.

I would point my sysadmin to this [thread from the RedHat mailing list from 2009](http://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/2009-May/msg00082.html).  There are 3rd party packages available so you don't have to compile from source

> If the version of php you need is not
> available in rhn you could use some
> 3rd party repos like rpmforge, ATrpms
> or the Remi Collet Repository that is
> specially made for mysql 5.1 and
> php5.2.9 under EL5.

I would be more concerned about PHP 5.1 branch security issues than something that might come up with WordPress.

### Edit:

Also found this official RedHat announcement from Jan 2011 [RHEL 5 now shipping with PHP 5.3.](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHEA-2011-0069.html)

Answer (score 8):

No, older versions are not updated.

Aside: [PHP 5.1.6 is **five years** old.](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.6) Even if WordPress would offer patches for 3.1.2 – you missed more than 100 security fixes for PHP, so WordPress isn’t your main problem anyway.

Comment: I am running RedHat Enterprise Linux and up to until recently the official packages only provided PHP 5.1.6. Luckily as of RHEL 5.6 they now provide PHP 5.3 packages. I know I could have compiled PHP from source but my system administrator did not want to do that. As far as security goes I believe RedHat incorporates all security fixes into their packages.

Comment: @ejunker I’m well aware of the logistical problems for PHP updates. But in the last weeks a lot of backwards compatible code has been removed from WordPress. New patches may be not compatible with older versions, so they have to be written and tested **twice** – and released later. This would be bad for everyone.

Comment: As php is not developed by redhat there is really no chance that there have been security fixes and php is now a whole new sub-version things have changed it is best to update to the latest php as hackers look for exploits and will use them to there best

Comment: FYI, WordPress 3.2 is dropping support for anything less than PHP 5.2.x and MySQL 5

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not patch older versions, so you will have to upgrade or manually apply patches yourself.